# Regular expression to validate the pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

The pattern I need is below:

- MA should be the first two characters of a string
- The third character should be hyphen (`-`)
- Characters 4 to 10 can be any numeric numbers (`0-9`)
- The eleventh character should be hyphen (`-`)
- Characters 12 to 15 can be any numeric numbers (`0-9`)

Example:

```
MA-1234567-1234
```

I have tried this:

```
/^(MA*)[0-9]{7}([0-9]{4})$/
```

Comment: We aren't here to do work for you, please post an attempt at the problem and then we can help you with it if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry i new to this stack over flow.

Comment: i tried the below thing 
/^(MA*)[0-9]{7}([0-9]{4})$/

Comment: No problem, please post an attempt at the question and then we will be more than happy to help you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Do you need to extract any of it or just verify the string matches the format?

Comment: Just verify the string in a text box as above i mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex you were using is missing the dashes between character sets, try this:

```js
/^MA-\d{7}-\d{4}$/
```

Note that to incorporate this with an input box you would need to test against this Regex on keyup, something like this:

```
var re = /^MA-\d{7}-\d{4}$/;
$('#code').keyup(function() {
    if (re.test(this.value)) {
        console.log('The code is valid...');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pck8w3bv/)

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote/accept an answer.

Comment: Hi  what if want the below two patterns with or condition it can be any of these two patterns  : CW291291 (or) MA-1234567-1234

Comment: Then you would need to change the pattern to suit that. I would suggest opening a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there you were missing dashes for separators and you don't need the paranthesis if you don't want to extract any of the information.

Correct regex is:

```
/^MA-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

**Edit to satisfy new requirements**
To match both: CW291291 and MA-1234567-1234

Use the pipe symbol '|' with both patterns to match either one:

```
/^CW[\d]{6}|MA-[\d]{7}-[\d]{4}$/
```

Comment: Hi gabriel
what if want the below two patterns with or condition 
it can be like this : CW291291 (or) MA-1234567-1234